# Horizontally centering text in a nested div that's set to justify

Tags: html, css, nested, text-align

I'm trying to create a responsive website (not using flex).  I need to create a title over two `display:table` cells, and I'd like it to be centered.  The main div holding the table is `text-align:justify`.  Nothing I seem to do fixes it!

I've tried nearly everything I can find on the subject:
`text-align:center;`

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
```

just plain `margin: 0 auto;`
and numerous combinations of the above.  The text remains stubbornly in the right corner.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="novel novelleft">
    <div class="noveltitle">TITLE</div>
      stuff
  </div>
  <div class="novel novelright">
      more stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.novel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last:left;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelleft {
  width: 40%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelright {
  width: 60%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.noveltitle {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My apologies if that's not right, I'm new here.  Thanks for any help!

EDIT
[Here's what it's doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5czG.jpg)
[What I want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hlf0.jpg)

Comment: I really don't understand your objective. Can you include an image to show what you want?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're not using flex or any other display properties? I don't see the point why the cells have to be display: table.

Comment: @AndyHoffman - added pics for you

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure what you mean by 'other display properties'.  To answer your question about not using flex: a) I'm very unfamiliar with it, and still learning the more basic parts of CSS.  b) I'm trying to make this website accessible to as many people as possible.  My understanding is that Flex is...maybe not bleeding edge, but certainly not supported by older browsers.  I could be wrong though - it happens a lot :)  c) I have them as `display: table` in order to maintain them both being the same size regardless of content.  Anything else results in uneven columns...

Comment: The code you now have does not produce the screenshot saying "Here's what it's doing".

Comment: @MrLister - no.  The instructions on asking a question say not to put the entire file into the question, so I only put the parts that were causing the issue....was that wrong?  The 'here's what it's doing' image is only a visual representation, as requested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use `div`s to simulate a table, then go all the way with it.

- Use `table-caption` for your table's title
- The left and right cells are a group, so surround both cells in a `table-row` and that `table-row` with a `table-row-group`

```css
.novel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.novel-caption {
  display: table-caption;  
  caption-side: top; 
  text-align: center; 
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;  
}

.novel-row-group {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.novel-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
}

.novel-row-group {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.novelleft {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  width: 50%;
}

.novelright {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #fff;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="novel">
  <div class="novel-caption">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <div class="novel-row-group">
    <div class="novel-row">
      <div class="novelleft cell">stuff</div>
      <div class="novelright cell">more stuff</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great within the confines of my site.  I was borrowing from W3C for the responsive table thing, and I guess it was incomplete?  Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table with a centered caption, just use a table with a centered caption.

```css
.novel {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelleft {
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelright {
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.noveltitle {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="novel">
 <caption class="noveltitle">TITLE</caption>
 <tr>
  <td class="novelleft">stuff</td>
  <td class="novelright">more stuff</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you prefer not to use <table> elements, you can use use divs, but you need to keep the proper table structure:

```css
.novel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelrow {
  display: table-row;
}
.novelleft {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.novelright {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 13%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.noveltitle {
  display: table-caption;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="novel">
 <div class="noveltitle">TITLE</div>
 <div class="novelrow">
  <div class="novelleft">stuff</div>
  <div class="novelright">more stuff</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are couple of answers that will obviously work I'd assume. I still think you should be open to using flex and then providing backward compatibility to IE with rather simpler CSS.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Centered Title Goal
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="novel">
      .novelLeft
    </div>
    <div class="novel">
      .novelRight
      <div>
      .novelRight
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.novel {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.novel:nth-child(1){
  background:#404040;
}
.novel:nth-child(2){
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
```

This will create a flexbox and as a fallback to IE where flex property doesn't work, the novelLeft and novelRight will be set to inline-block of width:50%. It's way more cleaner than doing the ancient table outlines. And as you can see, extra content on novelRight doesn't matter either.

https://jsfiddle.net/4q6f9zy7/3/